# Yii2 recursion of the tree menu?

Tags: php, recursion, yii2

Good night all! Help please in the recursion, where I made a mistake, I need to output the categories, as in the last example!

Model:

```
    protected function buildTree($data, $rootID = 0)
{
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($data as $id => $node) {
        if ($node->parent_id == $rootID) {
            unset($data[$id]);
            $node->childs = $this->buildTree($data, $node->id);
            $tree[] = $node;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

public function getTree()
{
    $data = Category::find()->all();
    return $this->buildTree($data);
}
```

View:

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() 

foreach ($tree as $cat) {
echo '<br><div class="spoiler-title">' . $cat['title'] . '</div>';
printNode($cat);
}

 function printNode($cat, $level = 1)
{
if (count($cat['childs']) > 0) {

    foreach ($cat['childs'] as $child) {

        for ($j = 1; $j < $level; $j++) {
            echo '------- <b>';
        }

        echo '' . $child['title'] . '</b><br>'; 
        //echo $form->field($model, $child['title'])->checkbox();
        //I want to do a checkbox, get an error, do not understand $ 
        //form and $ model

        if (count($child['childs']) > 0) {
            printNode($child, $level + 1);
        }
    }
 }
 }
  $form = ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

That's how I get the tree, this is with your code

```
root
    category
    category
    category
    ---- <b>subcategory</b
    ---- <b>subcategory</b
    ---- <b>subcategory</b
    ---- <b>subcategory</b
    category
    category
```

I need to make checkboxes in subcategories, but I get an error, in the code I wrote in the comments, your code works, but I can not change it my needs as a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also add recursion in view when you print tree.
Try this in view:

```
$form = \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin();

foreach ($tree as $cat) {
    printNode($cat);
}
function printNode($cat, $level = 1) {
    echo '<br><div class="spoiler-title">' . $cat['title'] . '</div>';
    if (count($cat['childs']) > 0) {
        foreach ($cat['childs'] as $child) {
            echo \yii\helpers\Html::checkbox('someName[]') . ' ' . $child['title'] . '<br>';
            if (count($child['childs']) > 0) {
                printNode($child, $level + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
\yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::end();
```

Comment: I definitely have to display categories in the view, so that later I could make checkboxes from them, that's why I'm doing in view foreach

Comment: Try to debug if your tree structure have built correctly. If its proper tree you should use recursion to show all nodes and their children. I edited my function and added indent to print proper levels of nodes. Try it and check what will be displayed?

Comment: Thank you very much Marcin Gorde, earned, another question to you, how to do like this
1Category
     2<b>Category</b>
           3----- Category
           3----- Category
           3----- Category
     2<b>Category</b>
           3----- Category
           3----- Category
           3----- Category
     2<b>Category</b>

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean? You'd like to add specific formatting for parent node? Every node have own children and they are printed as list below parent. This is the same for each level of tree. How would you like to show your tree?

Comment: Here is an example as in the picture
http://s019.radikal.ru/i603/1703/ed/ddcad203212d.png

Comment: I need help please!

Comment: In case in this picture you have tree with 3 level (root, category, and subcategory). You can display your tree using my solution. If you'd like to have output similar to your picture try to add proper html formatting to specific node. I can't help you if you don't show your code and whole tree structure. Try to edit your example and show me what is displayed

Comment: I added the code to the top and showed you an example of outputting my tree!

Comment: As in function to make subcategories by checkboxes?

Comment: You can render checkbox with Html helper. To use Active checkbox you should use model with special attribute to store checkbox value.  [yii2-active-form-guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html)